# How to animate text being revealed on the screen

Tags: animation

[image]

An animation of an object appears under something small or invisible to camera

Comment: I don't quite under stand what you are asking, nor what your description is pointing at. Could you please be a little more specific with your question.

Answer (score 8):

From my experience text objects do not work very well with booleans (due to some letters in some fonts being non-manifold).

This is a method that can be adapted to work on anything:

- You need to create a gradient mask for your material that will "stay static" despite the object movement (you do that by using *object* mapping and adding/subtracting the object's position from it):

  [image]

  [*link to full image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4syVK.png)

  Great thing about a mask is that it can be faded on the interface.
- The *Add node* is just driven by the text `position.x`.
- The mask is used to mix *Transparent* and any other shader.
- If you need to place such *Text* somewhere you need to parent it to something first and move it through parent.

This is the result:

[image]

And the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Looking great, though I wonder how to make an animation that simulates a keyboard typing.

Comment: @Gonzou You just need to move the text by increments, that's all, it's not very clear from the question what the intention is..

Comment: Would be non-trivial to define the increments for non-mono-spaced fonts.

Comment: @ajwood yep, very true. That would be a job for another addon or better for the one that exists but improved. It would have to measure the width and spacing of characters and offset the position of text accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**Not quite what the OP asked...**, since in the question the words appear backwards, form end to beginning of the word... (but maybe someone will find it useful...)

There is an [addon](http://www.pasteall.org/38778/python) to make a typewriter effect quite easily.

Get it here: http://urchn.org/post/typewriter-blender-addon

Once you enable it in the User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>),

[image]

Animating the text is quite easy, by changing the value on the character count.

[image]

Moving the text as it gets written you can get something like this:

[image]

To get a proper typewriter effect set your interpolation for all keyframes **Constant**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a typing text addon here: https://github.com/meta-androcto/blenderpython/blob/master/scripts/addons_extern/animate_text.py

I haven't used it in a long time, but it still works in 2.75. The addon claims it is under the tool shelf in the 3D view, but the settings are *actually* under the text properties. Activate the addon and the new settings will appear at or near the bottom of the text properties.

I made a video describing basic usage. There's more, but I don't know the addon very well. I don't know how to embed on SE, so I guess a link will suffice.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrbIHxhNzrY

Comment: seems like this is a newer/combined version of the addon linked on my answer. But I'm trying to play with the **animate text?** options on it but cannot get it to animate anything... Can you please elaborate on your answer as to how it is used?