# How to create a typing text-object animation ?

Tags: animation, text-object

[image]

As for the video editor in Blender, I would simply make the five pictures in the drawing and put them one after the other onto a channel. But how to make the same animation if the text is made out of 3d objects in the default layout ? (for instance in order to make them rotate while they are typed )

Comment: See cegaton's answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/how-to-animate-text-being-revealed-on-the-screen

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Blender Typewriter Addon:

http://urchn.org/post/typewriter-blender-addon

copy and paste the code into the Text Editor, then press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to run the script.

Select your text object and you'll find a new panel into the Font Propery Panel:
[image]

Type the text in "source_text" field (NELLY).

Go to frame 0 and insert a keyframe for the character_count = 0 (mouse over the field and press <kbd>i</kbd>)

Go to frame 75, change character_count to 5 (text length) and press <kbd>i</kbd>

### EDIT: Animation Nodes Addon

If you need more control (such as animating letters size, rotation...), you could use the Animation Nodes Addon.

Here you can find a video showing an advanced text manipulation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li7R01PyXuI&index=26&list=PLFSQhJg6cGLKq8WbouMNBOHbMd7xUhuom