# Typing animation

Tags: animation

How do I make text appear like someone is typing it?

I tried transparency with color ramps but the keyframes don't appear on the timeline or dope sheet so I instantly gave up on that.

There was a typewriter addon or something but it's outdated, and I'm using Blender 2.81, EEVEE.

The build modifier would work if it didn't start building at the end of the sentence. Made me consider looking for fonts that were reversed.

Have tried answers below, the typewriter addon works perfectly but nothing appears in the render, and the animation nodes crash Blender mid-render. Nothing still works.

Comment: this is it, but compatible with 2.8* should be repaired https://gitlab.com/bkurdali/blender-addon-experiments/blob/master/typewriter_text.py

Comment: @RUben still says "update to 2.8x required" and can't be seen in the toolbars.

Comment: If you copy and paste the script into text editor run script you will see it works 100%... To install as  an addon for 2.81.x simply edit  `(2, 7, 2)` to `(2, 81, 0)`  before installing.  @RUben consider adding as updated answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/how-to-animate-text-being-revealed-on-the-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate text being revealed on the screen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/how-to-animate-text-being-revealed-on-the-screen)

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks so much. What i did before was download the .py file and installed it as an addon, but now it works. Thanks again, you're all lifesavers.

Comment: @batFINGER new problem, the text doesn't show up when i finally render it, so i'm basically stuck in square one again.

Comment: Looked into it, and same for me... didn't check render (_just assumed_).  However this will get it to render  as expected https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/a-script-to-render-each-frame-as-image-not-render-animation-in-2-8

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks, everything is working good now.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Perhaps make an answer re the steps taken.  @RobertGützkow seen anything re frame change font body update not rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting this out for anyone who still needs the solution. Geometry Nodes of latest Blender versions have made the solution to this problem a lot simpler now.

Node setup below. Just put your text in the String Node and slide the Length value on the Slice String node however you want.

[image]

Screenshot of Length value lower than number of letters in String node.

[image]

Note that I am not using a Text object. This is a mesh with the Geometry Input disconnected.

Comment: I wish String to Curves had more inputs like for Alignment and Overflow as well as font ( I know very heavy to implement efficiently )

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still looking for a simple way to do this without going full animation nodes, I've [updated](https://github.com/gandalf3/blender-typewriter-addon) the typewriter addon and fixed the invisible text when render bug. Currently tested and working on 2.83.

Comment: Thanks for this! Quick question regarding text objects in Blender: do you know if it's possible to access the size of the individual characters via Python? I can access kerning and some other character values, but found nothing for the size. I've been asking around for months for a way to set up drivers to control the size of characters (to make a simple ramping scale text animation), but no one knows. I can do it in Animation Nodes but I'd really want to have a built-in way.. I'm fearing this might lead to me having to dive in the source code even if I don't know anything about it yet :P

Comment: @AleksiTuomela As far as I know the only per-character attributes available are those in [`TextCharacterFormat`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.TextCharacterFormat.html).  I expect going animation nodes might be easier, but as far as exposing the size yourself goes, probably the place to start is [`rna_curve.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_curve.c$1301).

Comment: In particular, look at the `material_index` property for reference; you'll want to write similar getters and setters to `rna_ChariInfo_material_index_{get,set}`. That said, comments aren't the best place to talk, so if you have further questions please feel free to ping me in the [renderfarm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) anytime (I can't guarantee a fast response though)

Answer (score 3):

Check out Animation Nodes, there's a tutorial on how to do this exact effect. https://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/597-tutorial-typewriter-text-effect.html

Comment: I think animation nodes could be the right thing here, and it has been kept up to date, but that tutorial is not up to date (2015, whereas the OP asked about Blender 2.81).

Comment: OK the main difference is this (I missed it at first): In the tutorial, the node editing occurs in the "Compositor" view, whereas now there is a separate "Animation Nodes" view that brings up the appropriate node editor.

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Answer (score -2):

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Text*, press  <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and write what you want then press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> again then rotate or move how you like.

If you want it upright you can do <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, `90`

Comment: I think the asker was particularly interested in the part of making text disappear progressively