# Blender 2.8x bug

Tags: python

This code doesn't work at render time perhaps it's because a blender bug what do you think about, there's the same problem with animation nodes 2.1 ?
when i render an animation there no motion of the curve but in the viewport animation work and motion of the cure is present.

There's no error message in console

Configuration : blender 2.8x on Kubuntu 19.10

```py
import bpy



def nettoi():
    for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        print(o.name)
        if("myCurve" in o.name):
            print("found")
            bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(o)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(o)


nettoi()


# sample data
coords = [(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(coords)-1)
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('myCurve', curveData)
curveData.bevel_depth = 0.01

# attach to scene and validate context

bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link( curveOB )








def mafoncanim(scene):
    current = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
    empx = bpy.data.objects['Empty'].location.x
    empy = bpy.data.objects['Empty'].location.y
    empz = bpy.data.objects['Empty'].location.z
    polyline.points[1].co.x = empx
    polyline.points[1].co.y = empy
    polyline.points[1].co.z = empz


    if(current%15 == 0):

        #print(str(empx)+'  '+str(empy)+'   '+str(empz))
        print(str(current))






bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(mafoncanim)

'''
```

Comment: Bugs are off-topic for this site.  If you are asking whether this is  a bug or expected behaviour, please show t he error message.

Comment: Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161758/typing-animation-in-2-81 in that swapping font body doesn't render either.  See comment re rendering image for each frame.