# Apply a python script before each frame in an animation

Tags: python, animation

I am creating a video using blender and some of the animations in the video I create them using blender itself.

However, I have an animation which have some values that are updated via script. Basically I have some master points in space and a triangle and I want to compute the best match of the points with the triangle, so the triangle points depend on the master points, which are animated.

This animation is used later directly in the video.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. What could I do?

Comment: Take a look at [application handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) and [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168122/handler-frame-change-pre-doesnt-work-in-render).